# Webscraping selenium looop

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I am still handling with a view problems. I am finally able to load the whole page with a view window.scrollBy(..) commands...

The problem I am facing now is that I would like to filter all headlines out of a text. The text I would like to screen is shown with this command:

[Code]

```
main = driver.find_element_by_id("mrt-node-quoteNewsStream-0-Stream")  

print(main.text)
```

That works well and all the result is shown. Within these results I am now wanna filter, as mentioned above all headlines. This should work wit the following code:

```
articles = main.find_elements_by_tag_name("mrt-node-quoteNewsStream-0-Stream") # li
for mrt-node-quoteNewsStream-0-Stream in articles:
    header = article.find_element_by_class_name("M(0)")
    print(header.text)
```

Unfortunately it shows me the following syntax error message:

> File "", line 7
> for mrt-node-quoteNewsStream-0-Stream in articles:
> ^
> SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Line 7 is the one with the following one:

```
for mrt-node-quoteNewsStream-0-Stream in articles:
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `M(0)` is a dynamic class value. Update the question with the text based HTML.

Comment: thx for the input. But does the programm not have a problem line 7, the change you have mentioned would be in line 8. Does that make sense? (I am a beginner...)

Answer (score 1):

This line of code returns a *list* of elements:

```
articles = main.find_elements_by_tag_name("mrt-node-quoteNewsStream-0-Stream")
```

So `articles` is a *list* of [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) and each of them looks like:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="04a9fac269c3a9cb724cc72769aed4e0", element="1b8ee8d0-b26a-4c67-be10-615286a4d427")>
```

As per your second set of code trials, `mrt-node-quoteNewsStream-0-Stream` is the `tag_name` and you must not look for the `tag_name` within the element.

Comment: Thx, for your answer! Exactly I would like to return a list with all the headlines. If I don't need to look for the tag_name, what else do I have to look for?

Comment: @Bebbi This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do? Feel free raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: I am trying to get all the headlines. I've copied the part where the healines are in:

So Articles should list me all the headlines, here for example the headline is "The Most Important Chinese Invention Ever!"

The code on the page is as follows

<span data-reactid="51">The Most Important Chinese Invention Ever!</span>